# Filter the row containing an exact word and highest value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have a table (Master sheet) in Google Sheets that looks something like this:

[image]

https://ethercalc.org/t8f0ze0kyx6a

I need to filter out an entire row of information on a separate sheet (Last Lesson) but only pertaining to someone's last lesson, eg. Sam and his third lesson. I've tried to add various different things to my filter option but with no success. My knowledge of Excel/Google Sheets is basic so if there is another way to go about this without the filter option do share.

Comment: Welcome. Please do share a link to a test sheet. Also, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well .

Comment: =FILTER(A2:M9, A2:A9="Sam")

This is what I used to get a list of lessons for this person. I tried incorporating a max function into this but it would either just give me a highest lesson value and not for the required name, or it would return an error.

Comment: A link to a test sheet would be very helpful and a real time saver. You can edit your question and add it there.

Comment: I am a bit confused about what your end result should be. Please have a look at [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hp5og8pml4n48TOMAHJKnbQaP4fVLaveh-rGsQWwUDc/edit#gid=982261157&range=A5) and tell me which solution you seek for, so I can turn it to an answer.

Comment: On this separate sheet I want to have a list of each person's last lesson copied from the master sheet. That's why I thought filter option would be a good idea. I don't want the data removed from the master list, only copied to a new list.The master list will grow with time so if for example I have 55 lessons with Sam, 49 with Ana, etc. I need that last lesson info displayed (55th for Sam and 49th for Ana). I figured Max function could work there but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Please edit/update your question with the [above comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/134707/filter-the-row-containing-an-exact-word-and-highest-value-in-google-sheets#comment123163_134707). It is vital to help everyone understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a formula combining several functions so as to achieve what you need. The working formula is the following:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR
     (VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(Master!A1:A20),
        QUERY({Master!A1:M15},"Select * Order By Col13 Desc"),
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13},FALSE)))
```

**EDIT**
In your comment you mention:

> Last lesson: The plan is to have everything from row 10 and below and
>   column E and onward grouped. When a name is chosen in row 3 it should
>   pull the info of that person's last lesson (see Sam). Below this
>   little form is a filtered info from the main list of all the lessons.
>   I figured I could keep adding names in column N12 onward and create a
>   filter for each name to return their last lesson from New lesson
>   sheet. The list of names and lessons will expand! – Linda

Here is the [link to a working sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s2nEx7XtZSjpsf6WKLZvKki4EJeTBDAkWwWrDiE0mI0/edit#gid=1958271455&range=A18).

*PS: From your original Master sheet I deleted the redundant rows*.

Comment: Marika, thank you for your efforts. I can't quite get it to work on my end probably due to many other formulas I have going on, but hopefully I'll figure it out!

Comment: _"I can't quite get it to work on my end..."_. That is why I was insisting on **"Please do share a link to a test sheet"**. In any case, please do share a link to a test **Google Sheet**. We can help out.

Comment: I do not have a *test* sheet - only the main sheet which is used between me and my colleagues. As there are many sheets containing private information of our students I can not share the said file.

Comment: Create a new spreadsheet, make a copy of the sheets in question, alter/sanitize students info, share with the world. _(you already did the same when tried to share through ethercalc)_.

Comment: I've made your solution work! Can you just explain to me, when you find time, what each segment of this function does in case I ever need this type of thing again?

Comment: **You too can contribute to the community** by taking the following steps as mentioned before. You do need to **edit/update your question** with the correct info as well as replace the link to ethercalc with the **link to your "Test version"** (which you deleted along with the comment mentioning it).  Also. **Do consider [upvoting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)**. _"Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful...."_